# jQuery .val() doesn't work for radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML code:

```
<form id="attorneyRegisterForm">
    <div class="captchaIcons">
        <label class="yourAgeLabel" for="rdo_1">
            <input 
                type="radio" 
                class="yourAgeRadio" 
                id="rdo_1" 
                name="attorneyRegister_age" 
                value="43b5b5755010e47acf5d549de05a205d" 
                title="Moon"
            />
            <i class="icon-moon ageIcons" title="Moon"></i>
        </label>
        ...
        <label class="yourAgeLabel" for="rdo_X">
            <input 
                type="radio" 
                class="yourAgeRadio" 
                id="rdo_X" 
                name="attorneyRegister_age" 
                value="c56f8bd55a15392e1039461c8006385c" 
                title="Flag"
            />
            <i class="icon-flag ageIcons" title="Flag"></i>
        </label>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="registerAttorneyButton" class="button primary tiny">
        <?php
            _e('Register', 'z');
        ?>
    </a>
</form>
```

and in my JavaScript file I have the following code:

```
var $attorneyRegisterForm       =   $('#attorneyRegisterForm');
var $attorneySubmitForm         =   $('a#registerAttorneyButton');
var $attorneyNonce              =   $('#attorneyNonce');
var $attorneyFirstName          =   $('#attorney_first_name');
var $attorneyLastName           =   $('#attorney_last_name');
var $attorneyEmail              =   $('#attorney_email');
var $attorneyPassword           =   $('#attorney_password');
var $attorneyPasswordConfirm    =   $('#attorney_password_confirm');
var $yourAgeRadio               =   $('#attorneyRegisterForm input[type="radio"]');

if($attorneyRegisterForm.length > 0)
{
    $attorneyRegisterForm.on(
        'submit.attorney',
        function(e)
        {
            $data   =   {
                fName   :   $attorneyFirstName.val(),
                lName   :   $attorneyLastName.val(),
                email   :   $attorneyEmail.val(),
                pass    :   $attorneyPassword.val(),
                passC   :   $attorneyPasswordConfirm.val(),
                age     :   $yourAgeRadio.val(),
                s       :   $attorneyNonce.val()
            };

            console.log($data);

            e.preventDefault();
       }
    );

    $attorneySubmitForm.on(
        'click',
        function(e)
        {
            $attorneyRegisterForm.submit();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    );
}
```

Now the problem is that while I am selecting a `radio` from the HTML form, the jQuery always returning the first radion value, and not the value of the selected one.

Is my javascript wrong ? Or should I try another method to retrieve the radio button ?

Comment: Use `:checked` option to get the selected radio button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [**:checked**](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) Selector

```
 $('#attorneyRegisterForm input[type="radio"][name="attorneyRegister_age"]:checked')
```

Comment: this will get the value of radio buttons from different group types as compared to mine that get's only the value for the attorneyRegister_age name group

Comment: You will create an error this way, since you didn't use double quotes or escaped single quotes on your name attribute selector. You should make the name selector either `[name="attorneyRegister_age"]` or `[name=\'attorneyRegister_age\']`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following jQuery to get the selected radio button for the name group

```
 $("input[name='attorneyRegister_age']:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Added `:checked` in jquery selector

```
 $('.yourAgeRadio:checked').val();
```

Comment: The #attorneyRegisterForm  at the beginning of the selector is already an overkill. Also, your selector will select all radio buttons. My selector will only select radio button from the attorneyRegister_age name group.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the id of input type radio in JS. Change

```
$yourAgeRadio               =   $('#attorneyRegisterForm input[type="radio"]');
```

to

```
$yourAgeRadio           =   $('input[type="radio"]:checked');
```

**Sample**

```
$(document).on('change','input[type="radio"]',function(){
    var $yourAgeRadio =   $('input[type="radio"]:checked');
   alert($yourAgeRadio.val()); 
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KeqQX/)